# Django admin list_display show full text on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, django-templates, django-admin

There is a TextField named **address**.
It usually contains more than 100 characters.
I can truncate the string but I want the following to happen:
Full text should appear on mouse hover on the truncated part.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to edit the address in `list_display` then you can just create a readonly field and use that:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
         css = {
             'all': ("styles.css",)
         }

    list_display=(
        ...other fields,
        list_display_address,
    )

    def list_display_address(self, instance):
        return format_html(
            '<span class="truncated_address" title="{}">{}</span>', 
            instance.address,
            instance.address
        )
```

- The way a readonly field works is by returning the value of a method on the modelAdmin.
- The title attribute sets the mouse over text.
- By adding the following to our `styles.css` we can truncate the address if it's too long. (I'm assuming it is on a single line):

```
.truncated_address{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```